# Simulación se series de tiempo en R

Tags: r, rstudio

Esta es el código para simular (1) serie de tiempo, ahora quisiera generar (1000) series de tiempo de 300 observaciones cada una,¿Cómo varia el loop para este objetivo?, algunas ideas? gracias

```
#################
# Simulación
#################

m = 300 # número de observaciones a simular
mu = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
Qt = diag(c(0.02,0.004,0.0001,0.0001,0.0001,0.0001,0.0001,0.0001,0.0001,0.0001,0.0001,0.0001,0.0001))
nt = mvrnorm(m,mu,Qt) 
nt = t(nt) 

Bsim = matrix(0,13,m)
Ge = 1.3
et = rnorm(m,0,sqrt(Ge))
Ysim = numeric(m) # serie simulado
Ysim[1] = et[1]

# Proceso de simulación
for (j in 2:m) {
  Bsim[,j] = Tt%*%Bsim[,j-1] + nt[,j]
  Ysim[j] = Zt%*%Bsim[,j] + et[j]
}
```

Comment: No se realmente para qué necesitas 1000 y cómo piensas almacenarlas / usarlas. Si cada simulación así generada es distinta, basta con meter todo tu código en un bucle `for (simulacion in 1:1000) { ... }`. No sé si eso es lo que buscas. Saludos

Comment: ¿Que valor tiene `Qt`?

Comment: Qt es matriz de covarianzas, Qt = diag(c(0.02,0.004,0.0001,0.0001,0.0001,0.0001,0.0001,0.0001,0.0001,0.0001,0.0001,0.0001,0.0001))

Comment: Para almacenar, Ysim sería una matriz de 300 x 1000 donde cada columna sería una simulación.